# Edit hyperlinks in nested tags that aren't on separate lines

Tags: regex, linux, perl

I have an interesting problem. I wrote the following perl script to recursively loop through a directory and in all `html` files for `img/script/a` tags do the following:

- Convert the entire url to lowercase
- Replace spaces and %20 with underscores

The script works great except when an image tag in wrapped with an anchor tag. Is there a way to modify the current script to also be able to manipulate the links for nested tags that are not on separate lines? Basically if I have `<a href="..."><img src="..."></a>` the script will only change the link in the anchor tag but skip the `img` tag.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Find;

$input="/var/www/tecnew/";

sub process {
        if (-T and m/.+\.(htm|html)/i) {
                #print "htm/html: $_\n";

                open(FILE,"+<$_") or die "couldn't open file $!\n";
                $out = '';
                while(<FILE>) {
                        $cur_line = $_;
                        if($cur_line =~ m/<a.*>/i) {
                                print "cur_line (unaltered) $cur_line\n";
                                $cur_line =~ /(^.* href=\")(.+?)(\".*$)/i;
                                $beg = $1;
                                $link = html_clean($2);
                                $end = $3;
                                $cur_line = $beg.$link.$end;
                                print "cur_line (altered) $cur_line\n";

                        }
                        if($cur_line =~ m/(<img.*>|<script.*>)/i) {
                                print "cur_line (unaltered) $cur_line\n";
                                $cur_line =~ /(^.* src=\")(.+?)(\".*$)/i;
                                $beg = $1;
                                $link = html_clean($2);
                                $end = $3;
                                $cur_line = $beg.$link.$end;
                                print "cur_line (altered) $cur_line\n";
                        }
                        $out .= $cur_line;

                }
                seek(FILE, 0, 0) or die "can't seek to start of file: $!";
                print FILE $out or die "can't print to file: $1";
                truncate(FILE, tell(FILE)) or die "can't truncate file: $!";
                close(FILE) or die "can't close file: $!";
        } } find(\&process, $input);

sub html_clean {
        my($input_string) = @_;
        $input_string = lc($input_string);
        $input_string =~ s/%20|\s/_/g;
        return $input_string; 
}
```

Comment: I see another problem in your script: what if tag attributes are located on several lines? <a\n title="..."\n href="...">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using a real parser instead of regexps? Regexps are [not suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege) for parsing HTML! Consider using a parser like [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Parser).

Comment: Or if you have validating HTML, use XML::LibXML.

Comment: @reinierpost Validating `HTML` need not be `XML`. Use an `HTML` parser to parse `HTML`.

Comment: I ended up using HTML::TokeParser::Simple. It is much cleaner and easier to manipulate HTML elements.

Thank you

This is an awesome site.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually suggest to get whole HTML text into memory and make a multiline search and replace with a RE matching whole tag:

```
text =~ s/(<a[^>]+href=")([^"]+)("[^>]+>.*?</a>)/$1 . &html_clean($2) . $3/ge
```